# Accessing an object using another object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three classes like this :

```
public class Cancellations
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string CustomerID {get; set;}
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
}

public class Service
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string CustomerID2 {get; set;}
    public string ServiceName {get; set;}
}

public class Bill
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string CustomerID3 {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
}
```

There is such a relation in these databases :  `Service.ID=Cancellations.CustomerID`  and `Bill.CustomerID3 = Service.CustomerID2` .
What I'm trying to achieve is that how can I get the correct city when I have CustomerID in Cancellations object. Can you give me tips about that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?... Look at `Join`s and then write the linq query. Also I suggest looking at navigation properties - so you will have an easier life with joins

Comment: @GiladGreen There is no navigation property in these configuration. I felt that I should use joins but I couldn't figure out how. Thanks.

Comment: Then please show something you have tried.. You are member for 4 years... you know how it works :)

Comment: The names of your PK / FK properties appear to be random junk. A service being a customer and more customer things being related by numbered customer id properties... not mission critical, but this is how future maintainance nightmares are created.

Comment: @grek40 Yes, I'm aware of that but this architecture is already done.

Comment: @jason so basically, you are already part of that future where someone has to deal with the nightmare? Congratulations... show your work an we'll try to help.

Comment: Bill model have no idea about Cancellations model .Then what do you mean by architecture? :)@jason

Comment: Actually, what's the relation between `Service` and `Bill`? It looks like it could be many:many, in which case the whole question is falling apart.

Comment: *Service.ID=Cancellations.CustomerID* is this a typo? because first field is `int`, the second - `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a straight forward join:

```
var result = (from c in db.Cancellations
              join s in db.Service on c.CustomerID equals s.ID
              join b in db.Bill on s.CustomerID2 equals b.CustomerID3 
              select new { c.Id, c.CustomerName, b.City }).ToList();
```

2 recommendations:

1. Rename your properties/classes - it feels they make little sense
2. Look up Navigation Propertires

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the CustomerID then:

**With C# and Linq**

```
using System.Linq;

--

// Suppose this is your cancellation object's CustomerID
int _customerID = 123;

--

var resultObj = from billObj in Bills 
            join serviceObj in Service on Service.CustomerID2 equals billObj.CustomerID3
            join cancellationObj in Cancellation on Cancellation.CustomerID equals serviceObj.ID
            where CancellationObj.CustomerID == _customerID
            select new { Bills = billObj };

--

String City = resultObj.Select(x => x.City).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would suggest you give your objects more meaningful names if possible.